# AWS DynamoDB Transactions with JavaScript: One or more parameter values were invalid

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, transactions, amazon-dynamodb

Help me, Obi-Wan...

I'm trying to do a `docClient.transactWrite(params)`, where my `params` look like (there are other fields too, trying to keep this fairly short):

```json
{
  "TransactItems": [
    {
      "Put": {
        "Item": {
          "slug": {
            "S": "marbled_crockpot_cheesecake"
          },
          "tag": {
            "S": "metadata"
          },
          "recipe_name": {
            "S": "Marbled Crockpot Cheesecake"
          }
        },
        "TableName": "recipes-table-dev"
      }
    },
    {
      "Put": {
        "Item": {
          "slug": {
            "S": "marbled_crockpot_cheesecake"
          },
          "tag": {
            "S": "marbled"
          },
          "recipe_name": {
            "S": "Marbled Crockpot Cheesecake"
          }
        },
        "TableName": "recipes-table-dev"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As near as I can tell by looking at [this example](https://medium.com/signiant-engineering/using-dynamodb-transactions-to-model-relational-data-c13619ca58ae) and [the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#transactWriteItems-property) it's fine, but whenever I run it I get to following error:

```
ERROR   Error performing transactWrite { cancellationReasons:
[ { Code: 'ValidationError',
Message:
'One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for key slug
 expected: S actual: M' } ],
```

I should point out that the Primary partition key is `slug (String)` and the Primary sort key `tag (String)`.  So I don't understand the `Type mismatch for key slug expected: S actual: M` phrase: If it's expecting `S`, well, that's what I sent, right?  I don't see an `M` in there anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the following when working with the [Document Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) (which offers a higher level API than the [`DynamoDB` class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html)):

> The document client simplifies working with items in Amazon DynamoDB by abstracting away the notion of attribute values. **This abstraction annotates native JavaScript types supplied as input parameters, as well as converts annotated response data to native JavaScript types**.
>
> The document client affords developers the use of native JavaScript types instead of `AttributeValue`s to simplify the JavaScript development experience with Amazon DynamoDB. JavaScript objects passed in as parameters are marshalled into `AttributeValue` shapes required by Amazon DynamoDB. Responses from DynamoDB are unmarshalled into plain JavaScript objects by the `DocumentClient`. The `DocumentClient`, **does not accept `AttributeValue`s in favor of native JavaScript types**.

This means that `slug` must be a plain string (`S`) and not a map (`M`) with attribute type.

The following should work:

```json
{
  "TransactItems": [
    {
      "Put": {
        "Item": {
          "slug": "marbled_crockpot_cheesecake",
          "tag": "metadata",
          "recipe_name": "Marbled Crockpot Cheesecake",
        },
        "TableName": "recipes-table-dev"
      }
    },
    {
      "Put": {
        "Item": {
          "slug": "marbled_crockpot_cheesecake",
          "tag": "marbled",
          "recipe_name": "Marbled Crockpot Cheesecake"
        },
        "TableName": "recipes-table-dev"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When working directly with the [`DynamoDB` class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html)  (lower level) attribute types must be specified.